# How to redirect the below component to new tab or new localhost

Tags: vuejs2

```
Nav.vue 
 data(){
   return{
   sidebar:[
      name:available,
      path:'/available'
      ]
```

In the above code I have declared the path for the component in a navigation link but I want to redirect this component in a new tab with a new localhost in vuejs

Comment: what have you tried?  there's [vanilla js redirecting](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp) and [vue-router redirecting](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html).  do either of those fit your needs?  there's not enough detail in the question to give a much more detailed solution.

Comment: `sidebar:[name:available,path:'/available']` is not a valid js array